# Fetching collection inside nhibernate session

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

One property has many photos. One photo belong to one property.

Inside my mvc controller I'm getting as parameter array of integers. These integers represents id of Photo which I want to delete.

I'm using nhibernate session and transaction to interact with db.

```
public ActionResult DeleteImgs(int[] data)
{
   Property p = null;
   using (ISession session = ....)
   {
      using(ITransaction transaction session.BeginTransaction())
      {            
         Photo photo = session.Get<Photo>(data[0]);
         p = session.Get<Property>(photo.Id);
         // found images and delete them
         foreach(int id in data)
         {
            Photo ph = session.Get<Photo>(id);
            //remove property from association so I can delete photo
            ph.Property = null;
            session.Delete(ph);
            session.SaveOrUpdate(ph);
         }
         //load property now with collection of remaining photos
         // here IS THE PROBLEM, Even there is photos inside collection
         // in debug I'm getting empty collection
         p = session.Query<Property>().
             .Fetch(x=>x.Photos).ToList() //empty?
             .FirstOrDefault;

         transaction.Commit();
      }
   }
   return View();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm sending just IEnumrable of photos to the view problem is solved like this, 
instead of sending lazy load property photos collection I'm sending IEnumerable of Photos like this

```
IEnumerable<Photo>photos = session.Query<Photo>().Where(x => x.Property == p).ToList();
```